# Rails: Check output of path helper from console

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Rails defines a bunch of magic with named routes that make helpers for your routes. Sometimes, especially with nested routes, it can get a little confusing to keep track of what URL you'll get for a given route helper method call. Is it possible to, using the Ruby console, see what link a given helper function will generate? For example, given a named helper like post_path(post) I want to see what URL is generated.

Answer (score 490, accepted):

You can show them with `rake routes` directly.

In a Rails console, you can call `app.post_path`. This will work in Rails ~= 2.3 and >= 3.1.0.

Comment: Just in a follow up of my own comment, seems this is possible from rails 3 console, in case you're using.

First, stick a fake request into your app object, by calling something like

`app.get "/"`

then just instance_eval the wanted methods, as they are now protected by default. Something like:

`app.instance_eval{ post_path(post) }`

Comment: Chubas' comment above worked in Rails 3. This is very useful when writing tests so I don't have to wait 1 minute to find out that the route is not correct. Also, it is great to test get and post calls. You don't need to call app.get first.

Comment: `app.teh_path` still works in Rails 4.0 and is useful for separating engine paths from main application paths.

Comment: If you're mounting an engine, e.g. `mount Spree::Core::Engine, :at => '/'`, then you'd access the paths via the engine name, like `app.spree_core_engine.some_path`. Or, if the "engine_name" is configured to be something different like [in this code](https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/v2.3.0/core/lib/spree/core/engine.rb#L5) then you'd do `app.spree.some_path`.

Comment: I had to add the `host` parameter like so: `app.article_url(my_article, host: 'mydomain.com')`

Answer (score 434):

you can also

```
include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
```

from inside a console sessions to access the helpers:

```
url_for controller: :users, only_path: true
users_path
# => '/users'
```

or

```
Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.users_path
```

Comment: This is much easier than the above solution IMO

Comment: this is the right answer to the original question in my opinion

Comment: This should be the best answer IMO

Comment: I can't be bothered to remember this, so I just come back here every couple days to copy/paste. Thanks.

Comment: best answer and it still works in the latest Rails (4.x)

Comment: Couldn't you also reference the url_helpers directly from the console, like `Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.users_path`?

Answer (score 35):

In the Rails console, the variable app holds a session object on which you can call path and URL helpers as instance methods.

```
app.users_path
```

Answer (score 23):

You can always check the output of `path_helpers` in console. Just use the helper with `app`

```ruby
app.post_path(3)
#=> "/posts/3"

app.posts_path
#=> "/posts"

app.posts_url
#=> "http://www.example.com/posts"
```

Answer (score 4):

Remember if your route is name-spaced, Like:

```
product GET  /products/:id(.:format)  spree/products#show
```

Then try :

```
helper.link_to("test", app.spree.product_path(Spree::Product.first), method: :get)
```

**output**

```
Spree::Product Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "spree_products".* FROM "spree_products"  WHERE "spree_products"."deleted_at" IS NULL  ORDER BY "spree_products"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
=> "<a data-method=\"get\" href=\"/products/this-is-the-title\">test</a>"
```

Comment: Thanks for the `spree` example, you're an angel that fell from heaven.

Answer (score 1):

For Rails 5.2.4.1, I had to

```
app.extend app._routes.named_routes.path_helpers_module
app.whatever_path
```

Answer (score 1):

[From rails 6](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68030668/1419402) `rake routes` doesn't exist.

You can run instead

```bash
rails routes
```