# How to access *_path and *_url helpers in Rails 4

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I was reading [Rails: Check output of path helper from console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846247/rails-check-output-of-path-helper-from-console) and none of the solutions worked for me, presumably because they are all for Rails 2/3.

In Rails 4/5, how can I access the *_path and *_url helpers from the rails console?

Comment: Why does `rake routes` not work?

Comment: @Brennan I don't want to list them, I want to run the functions.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Running Rails 4, I get at them with:

```
app.root_path
=> "/"

app.users_url
=> "http://www.example.com/users"
```

Answer (score 15):

You can use `Rails.application.routes.url_helpers`

```
 Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.users_path
```

For the *_url versions, you'll have to tell it the host, or set a default

specify the host:

```
 Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.users_url(:host => 'http://example.com')
```

set a default:

```
Example::Application.configure do
  routes.default_url_options = {:host => 'http://example.com'}
end
```