# Lookup static route from url

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my `routes.rb` file I have this entry, namespaced under info:

```
    get 'account-pending', to: 'info/account_pendings#index'
```

If I use a static route strong of `/account-pending` it will of course take me to the appropriate page, with `/account-pending` in the browser url.

I can ask for this route like this:

```
url_helpers.info_account_pendings_path
```

But this returns:

```
/info/account_pendings
```

Can I ask for `info_account_pendings_path` and be returned `/account-pending` by Rails?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to actually use the `namespace` command in your routes file.

```
namespace :info do
  get  'account-pending', controller: :account_pendings, action: index
end
```

Actually getting the path for a named route has been asked before, try: [Rails: Check output of path helper from console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846247/rails-check-output-of-path-helper-from-console)