# rake routes command not working - rake version 13.0.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake

`rake routes` on Terminal returns:

`rake aborted! Don't know how to build task 'routes' (See the list of available tasks with 'rake --tasks' /Users/jesseca-zapier/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:22:in 'eval' /Users/jesseca-zapier/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:22:in '<main>' (See full trace by running task with --trace)`

Installed rake version 13.0.3, updated bundle, installed/uninstalled rake

What I'm trying to do after that is to use `resources :routes` but it's not working as well. I suspect it is related to the above.

Answer (score 11):

we can not use `rake routes` in rails 6.
so, use `rails routes` instead of rake routes.

You can check what we can do with rails/rake

```
rake --task
```

and

```
rails -h
```

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that. May know if `resources :routes` is still applicable too?

Comment: in routes.rb right?
if so, it's same in every version.

Comment: One tip, you can use `rails routes --expanded` to have the routes listed in a table. Much easier to read